# How to prevent spaces around a binary relation in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, math-operators, subscripts, relation-symbols

I'm trying to add a subscript both before and after the `\cong` symbol, but the problem I'm having is that because it is a binary operator, I'm getting spacing between the prescript and the symbol. I have:

```
_{A}\cong_{B}
```

And this produces: [image]

Notice how the spacing is uneven.

Is there a way I can convince LaTeX to not treat `\cong` as an operator that adds spaces around it, so that I can get both subscripts evenly spaced?

Comment: `{\cong}`  ........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{\cong}` will be a mathord with normal letter spacing, so you probably want

```
\mathrel{{}_{A}{\cong}{}_{B}}
```

to get a relation with the subscripts around an inner mathord `\cong`.